# Save and Update operations in single Transaction of JPA not working as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

consider entity as user, it having some fields. here i am using jpa callback functions to update user information  of last update information. in test class I want to write junit method to evaluate whether these call back methods are working or not/ not only for functionality testing and code coverage purpose also. but if I follow below approach i am getting same time everytime, can anyone help on this.

```
@Entity
public class User {
     // user setter and getter methods

    @preUpdate
    public void preUpdateFunction() {
      this.lastUpdateDate = new Date();
   }

   @prePersist
   public void prePersistFunction() {
      // setting some user properties
      preUpdateFunction();
   }
}
```

// please ignore this configuration and annotations setup, I tested my class spring configuration working perfectly there is no issue with spring configuration.

```
@SpringConfiguration
@JpaTransactional
public class TestClass {


     @Autowired
     UserDao userDao;  // userDao implements JPA Repository

    // I am worrying about this functionality only
    @Test
    public void saveUpdateTest() {
          User user = userDao.save(new User(constructor arguments));
          user = userDao.findOne(user.getId());

          user.setName("Hello");   // here updating user object with existing property
          User updatedUser = userDao.save(user);


         assertEquals(user.getLastUpdateDate().getTime(), updatedUser.getLastUpdateDate().getTime());   

// assertion is failing, everytime i am getting same Time for two values. even I added //Thread.sleep(1000) between save and update operations, still i am getting same values.

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add the entire User entity class contents?

Comment: Why are you calling `findOne` when you already have a copy of the `User`? (It should work, but it doesn't make sense.) You also don't need to `save` changes with JPA. Also, what are these `@SpringConfiguration` and `@JpaTransactional` annotations?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- after saving, copy of the User still in persistence nature only. so to get the LastUpdateDate of that object i am retrieving from DB, on findOne operation JPA automatically flush and fetch from DB right. the annotations i am using for get the springContext, then i can autowired Dao and service classes, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If you want to check whether those `preUpdateFunction()`and `prePersistFunction` were called, you can use Mockito. It allows to check which methods, how many times and with which argument were called on particular object

Comment: @Ivan mockito is fine, but have a curious to know about my mistake here

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

You need to call **saveAndFlush**

```
User updatedUser = userDao.saveAndFlush(user);
```

### Long answer

From JPA spec (JSR 338 JPA 2.1):

> The PrePersist and PreRemove callback methods are invoked for a given entity before the
> respective EntityManager persist and remove operations for that entity are executed.

> The PreUpdate and PostUpdate callbacks occur before and after the database update operations to entity data respectively. These database operations may occur at the time the entity state is updated or
> they may occur at the time state is flushed to the database (which may be at the end of the transaction).

@PrePersist is invoked when entityManager persist operation is executed. Tricky part is the execution is usually delayed until next flush operation or transaction commit (hibernate default config). Generally, it depends on flush configuration and on jpa implementation.

Same also applies to @PreUpdate. In addition, JPA spec says it more specifically, it might occur when entity state is updated or when flushed to DB.

### Related links

https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf

https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-save-saveandflush-and-saveall